# Blob Data Type?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

Can blob data type store the video data also?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Storing video in a SQLite database is a horrible idea.  Don't do it.

Don't put large BLOBs in a database.  Put them in the filesystem next to your database file and then write the filenames or an URL to the database.  This will be a ton faster, will use the database much more efficiently, will minimize I/O (in that the video won't have to be broken up into the paging scheme of the database, and will make management of the videos easier (a filesystem `delete` of a file is a *ton* faster than a database having to excise a bunch of pages that contain the BLOB).

Putting BLOBs in the database is horribly inefficient and, quite possibly, will blow out your app's memory use, too (unless you have figured out a way to stream data from the database to the video decoder).

It will incur extra I/O, use more power, and performance will generally go to hell as you store more items in the database.   If you are mixing BLOBs with small datums in the database, you can quite easily end up with a pathologically fragmented database.  Auto-vacuuming will help, but it is yet more inefficiency, more I/O and more battery life consumed.

---

Yes, there are databases that handle BLOBs fairly well.  And they are completely irrelevant to this question whose only tag is "iPhone".

Note that the answer to the question "handles BLOBs and streaming media better than the filesystem" pretty much always requires that you are using a database that is reading/writing to/from a raw device -- a partition on a hard drive that is nothing but database contents.  Any other solution will necessarily be a layer on top of an existing filesystem and there will be cost, even if the database vendor has done all the engineering work (and it is huge) to match they database access I/O as much as possible with underlying filesystem semantics.

Comment: In addition the advantages of storing them as blobs are nearly nonexistent. There may be valid arguments for this kind of blob storage in enterprise systems with giant system-spanning databases that require crazy backup schemes and global data replication and such -- maybe -- but none of those things is true on an iOS device.

Comment: FWIW, there is one DBMS that does a fine job of storing video data, and the vendor (FrontBase) put some effort into working with the quicktime team to make it prefetch data smoothly.

Comment: Your answer is implementation dependent. SQLite might well be poor at BLOBs but it's easy to conceive of a database that wouldn't be, and there are obvious advantages to storing data within the database. For example, simpler updates and built-in support for replication. You need to make a judgement based on the implementation you're using and your specific requirements. Remember that your file system can also be thought of as a database and has exactly the same problems with fragmentation.

Comment: Given that the only tag is "iPHONE", I fail to see the relevance in most of these comments...

Comment: The headline of your answer is "Storing video in a SQLite database is a horrible idea. Don't do it" and you continue with "Don't put large BLOBs in a database." so I think you could forgive some readers for believing it was universally the case, especially in absence of information otherwise. So I think it's definitely relevant and your answer is better for it being mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The blob data type can be used to store any binary data.  Specifically it stands for B(inary) L(arge) Ob(ject) ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_%28computing%29))

Answer (score -1):

```
NSData *imageData;
NSURL *imageURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[videolistArray objectAtIndex:[number intValue]] valueForKey:@"video"] ];
if (imageURL) {
    imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
}

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

if (!documentsDirectory) {
    NSLog(@"Documents directory not found!");
}
NSArray *myWords = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[videolistArray objectAtIndex:[number intValue]] valueForKey:@"video"]] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/"]];

NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[myWords lastObject]];

[imageData writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
```

In This i store video in iphone document directory u just insert it into SQLite Data base w

Answer (score -2):

I use blog to store video in my SQLite DataBase and its working good,i have store more then 100 video in my database its take time to store that video

Comment: can you please give me an overview  of storing the video and image as well in blob data type?