# BLOB in SQLite?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite, nsdata

I have created a SQLite database with an id AUTOINCREMENT and image BLOB.

Now, I want to INSERT a image in the image column. I am a big objective-c nube and have been trying all sorts of stuff but they don't seem to be working. I know lots about MYSQl, but not SQLite and I can't seem to figure it out.

I have `uploadImage` (UIImage). I am using Matteo Bertozzi's SQLite wrapper [here](http://th30z.blogspot.com/2008/11/objective-c-sqlite-wrapper_8445.html). Here's some of my code I have after someone picks an image off their phone:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    [picker.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    uploadImage = image;

    NSData *dataForImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(uploadImage);

    [database executeNonQuery:@"INSERT INTO process (image) VALUES (dataForImage)"]; 

}
```

Thanks again!

Coulton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the language is Objective-C, not C++. :)

In general, shoving lots of images into a SQLite database is going to be inefficient, both in terms of potential memory use and I/O.  It'll be slower and use more resources.   Better to put the images into the filesystem and then refer to the filesystem from the SQLite database.

This is related to [Blob Data Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363755/blob-data-type)

Comment: Yes, I have heard that. But I am not planning to store any images in (15 at max). Thanks for the link, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 1):

Your executeNonQuery never actually passes your dataForImage parameter (you're just passing a string), so...

Change this:

```
[database executeNonQuery:@"INSERT INTO process (image) VALUES (dataForImage)"];
```

To this:

```
[database executeNonQuery:@"INSERT INTO process (image) VALUES (?);", dataForImage];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I used a NSlog and displayed the table in the console and I got this error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'